# What is the feminine of doctor (médecin)?

Tags: sens, genre, genre-biologique, professions

What is the feminine of doctor (médecin)?

I can't understand if there is feminine form for almost all professions.

Can you explain me please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no feminine for *médecin*, it is a noun of masculine gender which can refer to person of both sex (just like *personne* is a noun of feminine gender without any hint about the sex of the person).

There are some tentatives from official committees to give a feminine to jobs title, Kareen gave the Quebec one, [here](http://www.dglf.culture.gouv.fr/ressources/feminisation.pdf) is the French one.  I don't know the situation in Quebec but as far as I can tell, here the recommendations have not influenced the usage, and *une médecin* or *une médecine* aren't used (they aren't even cited in dictionaries I've consulted).

For *docteur* the situation is nearly similar, i.e. *un docteur* doesn't offer any indication about the sex.  But *une doctoresse* exist (and is restricted in usage to practitioners of medecine) and I've seen and heard *une docteur* and *une docteure* (for any kind of *docteur*) even if dictionaries ignore them.

Comment: The same goes for "Une sage femme" which to my knowledge is still called this way, when a man has the job :-)

Comment: @ArthurAttout, there is "maïeuticien".

Comment: "Une nourrice" too.

Answer (score 12):

There is no feminine form of *médecin* to speak of. It is used both for men and women, even though it is a masculine noun. If necessary, one could say "*une femme médecin*".

The *Office québécois de la langue française*, the Quebec French regulation office, which has been very pro-feminization of profession titles in the 1980's-1990's, says the following about *médecin* in its [job title feminization guide](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/feminin/aufeminin_final.pdf) (dated 1991):

> Les féminins réguliers de *marin* et *médecin* seraient, respectivement, *marine* et *médecine*, formes déjà utilisées pour désigner ces domaines d’activité. L’homonymie pouvant être gênante, l’Office propose de considérer *marin* et *médecin* comme épicènes. On aura donc : **une marin**, **une médecin**.

What it is saying is that adding an E to *médecin* creates an already existing word and that the newly created homonym would be awkward. So the proposal is to consider *médecin* as epicene, and that is how it is used today.

Comment: Does the *Office québécois* has any influence on the French language (of France)? If "no", maybe that answer is irrelevant(?)

Comment: @ring0, usage of Québec is also interesting. The real question is "does the office has any influence on the way French is used in Québec outside the administration?"

Answer (score 8):

There was a big discussion over gender equality and job titles.

It all began in 1984 when the prime minister (Pierre Mauroy, recently deceased) asked the general comission for terminology and neology about feminisation of job titles. The commission answer was clear, they were oposed to the project.

Despite the negative answer and due to political pressure, the french documentation published a catalogue of feminised name.

The french Academy had to intervene. Professors Georges Dumezil and Claude Levi-strauss write the text and give their position. The better way to fight gender inequality is to consider jobs titles as collective and neutral. this would also avoid language "heaviness". A reinforcement of the female position in the society by a feminisation of jobs title would be an illusion. Furthermore, a differentiation could be seggregating in some case, so the effect could be in total opposition to the initial goal of the feminisation.

The french academy advised not to use the feminised job titles.

They doesn't reccomend it but if the differentiation is really needed, they advised to use "la" before the job title. The official answer to your question is "la docteur".
The only exception would be for military grade and honorific titles ("docteur" is one of these titles), never ever use "la".

On the other hand, feminists argued that this wasn't a grammar question  but a sociolinguistical one. That job titles are considered masculine in everyone's mind and so can build resistance to feminisation of the workplace.

Note that in france, thanks to the academy, the "neutralists" won over the "feminists" and it is always akward to use a feminised name. La docteur could be a "neutralist" or a "feminist" and the better ways to go are to avoid using it or asking her choice.
From what I've heard, it is not the same in Canada, where the list of feminised name have been accepted. In Canada you can say "la doctoresse".

See here for the text: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-fonctions-grades-et-titres

Comment: I'd question the "thanks to the academy".  I doubt the Academy has much influence on practical usage.

Answer (score 5):

"*Doctoresse*" is the French feminine form of doctor. http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctoresse

---

"*Doctoresse*" est le feminin de *docteur*. http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctoresse

Comment: *Doctoresse* is very rarely used in France.

Comment: Some people may even have a pejorative feeling about this word.

Comment: @Gilles You base this on what? My mother is a physician, she tells me that older people call her "madame la doctoresse" all the time.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It might be regional. I've always heard *docteur* in Normandy and in the Paris area (where I meet people from many different regions).

Comment: It's very weird that "doctoresse" is very rare now, when everyone wants to feminize name, and don't use the names that already exist!!

Answer (score 4):

The Academy has recognised the feminisation of names and you'll likely see docteure more often than doctoresse. Here is an article on the subject: https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2019/02/28/l-academie-francaise-se-resout-a-la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers_5429632_3224.html

Comment: Voir aussi le rapport [ici](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rapport_feminisation_noms_de_metier_et_de_fonction.pdf), en particulier à la page 9. On nuance selon que la forme au féminin implique de prononcer différemment ou non...

Answer (score 0):

Feminisation of the language is a false problem... it looks like that the rights we want to install in our societies need to have aftereffects with the grammar of the language to exist : this is non-sense and a pain for the ear.

In France, the *Académie française* is the guarantor of the language against barbarisms and other insults.

Read [this article](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-et-de-fonctions), which was already suggested by lmorin, and you will understand everything.